# pip command to downgrade jupyter notebook

Tags: pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, downgrade

I installed jupyter notebook with pip using `python -m pip install jupyter` and nbextensions using `pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions && jupyter contrib nbextension install`

My current `jupyter-notebook` version is 6.1.6 which makes nbextensions to show blank tab as per this [thread](https://github.com/Jupyter-contrib/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator/issues/126) . However the solution is to downgrade the notebook to 6.1.5 version.

How do I do that using pip?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pip install notebook==6.1.5` will downgrade the jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a version number:

```
pip install jupyter-notebook==6.1.5
```

Comment: tried that, didn't work `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jupyter-notebook==6.1.5
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jupyter-notebook==6.1.5`